# How to get a URL from a new image using Cloud Function with Flutter?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

How I can get a URL from new Images in fire-storage with the Images name?

I am uploading an image with Flutter using [firebase_storage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_storage/versions/1.0.0#-readme-tab-) plugin

Code in flutter:

```
StorageReference ref =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("$stamp.jpg");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
    Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
    downloadableUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
```

but the image sizes are too big, thus I create a Cloud Function to generate lower quality images from this upload.

Cloud Fuction:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;

exports.onFileChange= functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
    const object = event.data;
    const bucket = object.bucket;
    const contentType = object.contentType;
    const filePath = object.name;
    console.log('File change detected, function execution started');

    if (object.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
        console.log('We deleted a file, exit...');
        return;
    }

    if (path.basename(filePath).startsWith('resized-')) {
        console.log('We already renamed that file!');
        return;
    }

    const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
    const metadata = { contentType: contentType };
    return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tmpFilePath
    }).then(() => {
        return spawn('convert', [tmpFilePath, '-resize', '500x500', tmpFilePath]);
    }).then(() => {
        return destBucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
            destination: 'resized-' + path.basename(filePath),
            metadata: metadata
        })
    });
});
```

How I can get the resize-image Url in flutter? I need to use this URL in data registration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no easy way.

I would maintain a table in Firebase with the original file name as key and the new file name as value.

You create the entry from your cloud function above and read it from Flutter using Firebase database access (Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore)

Comment: This is indeed the most common approach, using the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore as a signaling mechanism/message bus. I most commonly make the Cloud Function trigger on a database write, which I then do from the client-side code after the image has been uploaded. The Cloud Function reads the metadata, finds the file and resizes it, and then writes the response back to a pre-agreed location. Nowadays you can also consider using a [Callable HTTPS function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for this.